# R compare with two dataframes by multiple conditions to extract rows

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
 x <- data.frame('a'=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),'b'=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),'c'=c(1,2,3,2,1,3))

    y <- data.frame('a'=c(1,2,3),'b'=c(1,1,1),'c'=c(1,2,3))
```

would like to extract rows from x as follow conditions:

```
 x$a==y$a & x$b==y$b+1 & (if y$c == 1, then x$c %in% c(2,3); if ...)
```

result should like:
x:
a b c
1 2 2
only row 2 in x match.
I have tried:

```
 z <- y[which(y$a == x$a & y$b == x$b+1),]
```

to match at lease the first two conditions, but not work, the result is null.
What is the suitable way to deal with it? Please help.

Comment: Could you show what the final data should look like? The logic is unclear(to me).

Comment: Like @NelsonGon said, knowing what the final data set should look like would be helpful, or plainly stating the conditions for each column/dataframe.

Comment: I have edited the quiz, only row2 in x would match( a = 1, b=2 which ==y$b+1, c =2 which y$c = 1, x$c should in (2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try to run an SQL statement with help of `sqldf`:

```
sqldf("select x.* from x join y where 
      x.a = y.a and 
      x.b = y.b + 1 and
      y.c = 1 and
      x.c in (2, 3)")
```

> ```
>   a b c
> 1 1 2 2
> ```

This returns the expected result for the given sample dataset. However, it needs to be tested with a production dataset.

The third and fourth condition are "fixed", e.g., `y$c == 1` and `x$c %in% c(2, 3)`. So, `x` and `y` can be filtered *before* joining:

```
sqldf("select u.* from 
      (select * from x where c in (2, 3)) as u
      join 
      (select * from y where c = 1) as v
      where u.a = v.a")
```

> ```
>   a b c
> 1 1 2 2
> ```

Perhaps, this might result in a performance gain (untested!)

This approach can also be used in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  filter(c %in% 2:3) %>% 
  inner_join(
    y %>% 
      filter(c == 1) %>% 
      mutate(bp1 = b + 1), 
    by = c("a", "b" = "bp1"))
```

> ```
>   a b c.x b.y c.y
> 1 1 2   2   1   1
> ```

Comment: should we have a better solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that a simple "merge" is due here (due to inequality), but here's an attempt:

```r
library(dplyr)
y %>%
  mutate(bp1 = b + 1) %>%
  inner_join(x, ., by = c("a", "b" = "bp1")) %>%
  filter(c.y == 1 & c.x %in% c(2, 3))
#   a b c.x b.y c.y
# 1 1 2   2   1   1
```

Note: the `.x` and `.y` are *coincidentally* the same as the frame from which they came, but that is just coincidence.

Comment: in filter section, looks like x and y should with same length? I encounter an error:

Comment: Error: Result must have length 237324, not 430037
In addition: Warning message:
In ku_11$TEXTURE_CODE == "S" & hor$TEXTURE_CODE %in% c("SL", "L") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: yeah, sorry, perhaps my answer will only work on your sample data